# C++ standard regex difference between std=c++11 and std=gnu++11

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, gcc, gnu

There seems to be a difference in regex behavior when comiling code using regex and gnu extensions.

The following code produces an exception when compiliing with -std=c++11, however -std=gnu++11 works:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    std::string rex { "\\[1\\]" };
    std::string str { "[1]" };
    std::regex regex(rex, std::regex::extended);
    auto match = std::regex_match(str.begin(), str.end(), regex);
    std::cout << "Result is " << match << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried gcc from 4.9.4 up to 9.2 with same behavior. Any ideas why this code behaves differently?

Comment: Is there no error message?

Comment: When using -std=c++11 I get a runtime exception of type regex_error, which of course could be caught.

Comment: [Can easily be replicated](https://godbolt.org/z/KRkCXv). And then we see that the exception message is "Unexpected escape character."

Comment: It is easy to replicate. But why does it work with gnu++11? I cant find any description about a possible extension concerning regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::regex::extended` uses [extended POSIX regular expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04). According to those syntax rules, a backslash can only precede a "special character", which is one of `.[\()*+?{|^$`. While a left bracket `[` is a special character, the right bracket `]` is not. So your regular expression should be `"\\[1]"` instead of `"\\[1\\]"` to be standard-compliant.

Looking at the standard library source code, there is the following in [regex_scanner.tcc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/regex_scanner.tcc#L417):

```
#ifdef __STRICT_ANSI__
      // POSIX says it is undefined to escape ordinary characters
      __throw_regex_error(regex_constants::error_escape,
                  "Unexpected escape character.");
#else
      _M_token = _S_token_ord_char;
      _M_value.assign(1, __c);
#endif
```

Which shows that it is a GNU extension to allow escaping non-special characters. I don't know where this extension is documented.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The interesting thing is, that the old regex.h implementation isn't strict about this. The actual code that I was adapting used regex.h and after changing to c++11 <regex> exceptions occurred.